# Why does my SVM accuracy decrease after tuning while it should be increasing?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, cross-validation

I am actually trying to do some classification work using svm using the e1071 package. The problem is before tuning when I use the svm function, I am getting an accuracy of around 58% but then when I try to tune it the accuracy massively goes down by 10% to 47%. I have tried tuning using different cost and gamma values but the result is still the same. The example of one of my tuning code I will provide you guys with here:

Code without tuning:

```
model<-svm(rating~.,data=train,kernel="radial")
summary(model)
Predictor<-predict(model,test)
confusionMatrix(table(Predictor,test$rating))

     summary(tune.svm(rating ~ ., data = train,
    +                  kernel = "radial", gamma = 10^(-1:1), cost = 10^(-1:1)))

    Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:

    - sampling method: 10-fold cross validation 

    - best parameters:
     gamma cost
       0.1  0.1
```

For code without tuning I am getting an accuracy of around 57%. Here is my Code with tuning:

```
> tuned<-svm(rating~.,data=train,kernel="radial",cross=10,gamma=0.1,cost=0.1)
> Prediction<-predict(tuned,test)
> confusionMatrix(table(Prediction,test$rating))
Confusion Matrix and Statistics


Predictor_1   1   2   3
          1   0   0   0
          2 257 467 257
          3   0   0   0

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.476
```

I have also tried setting:

```
1. gamma = 10^c(-1:10), cost = 10^c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

2. gamma = 10^c(10,20,30,50,60,70,80,90,100), cost = 
   10^c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)))

3. gamma = 10^c(-1:20), cost = 10^c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

The result is still exactly the same. Why is this happening? What should I be doing differently? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That might be a question for the CrossValidated board

Comment: Try other kernels. It does not appear as if rbf is working here.

Comment: Thanks for that.I have only worked with Linear and Radial kernels before. I chose radial because I was dealing with a multi class problem. There are three classes that I have got to classify the data points into. How do I choose the right kernel. Just a learner I am still. Any references else where would also be highly appreciated. Thanks so much :)